# Having a hard time handling errors caused by 'import'

Tags: javascript, error-handling, es6-modules, deno

code of test.js

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(i)
  try {
    const j = await import('./errorThrowingModule.js')
  } catch (error) {
    console.dir(error)
  }
}
```

code of errorThrowingModule.js

```
adsfasdfsdafas()
```

result of test.js (run by Deno)

```
0
ReferenceError: asdfasdfsdafas is not defined
  at file://~~~~~~
1
error: Uncaught ReferenceError: asdfasdfsdafas is not defined
  at file://~~~~~
```

I guessed the reason why the error was not caught in the second import as follows.

1. There's nothing wrong with importing itself. (look at the following codes for your understanding)

```
try {
  import('./errorThrowingModule.js')
} catch {
  // it never reaches here
}
```

```
try {
  await import('./errorThrowingModule.js')
} catch (error) {
  console.dir(error) // it reaches here
}
```

error is caught when awaiting promise is rejected by error thrown by the module,
not importing itself.

2. import is never executed twice.
   (This may not require further explanation.)
3. awaiting for a promise which has been rejected already does not cause the complexity of this situation

```
try {
  await Promise.reject(new Error())
} catch (error) {
  console.dir(error) // code reaches here
}
```

I don't know how exactly `import` acts when it's a second run.

maybe on a second run, code doesn't `await` an `import` at all.

I don't know how to handle the error caused by a module efficiently.

Comment: This looks like a bug in Deno to me. Your first snippet really should work and log the same error ten times. It might have to do with either `import` or top-level `await`.

Comment: thanks. Maybe i should use ```new Function``` instead to detour the problem. Or make sure that importing file has no error

Comment: Yes, try putting this in an `async function` to see if the behaviour changes - that would make it a tla bug.

Comment: I would try it later. Thank you so much.

Comment: maybe it's the problem of ```import``` itself. wrapping with an ```async```function didn't work

Comment: Try to add  catch (error). It's missing in your snippet